# Launching and killing multiple Java processes running on several platforms

Tags: java, deployment, process, kill, launch

Is there a way to do the following actions using a Java application:
1. Launch several hundred Java processes on several machines 
2. Be able to kill individual processes

Could this be done?

If it is too complicated, controlling these processes on a single machine could be a good start. Would appreciate an example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this can be done...albeit it's a pretty serious undertaking to make a system like this reliable.  (Certainly Hadoop and Storm do it internally...) It'd help to know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: As part of Load tests, I would like to launch many real clients that communicate with a server from different machines and IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your application.

For managing processes on multiple servers, consider using a distributed execution framework like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)

For a java based distributed computing application, consider a grid computing framework like [gridgain](http://www.gridgain.com/).

Comment: I thought of automating this control over processes using Java SW. Now that I have looked into both solutions, they could be a good lead to follow. gridgain is more for distributed computing but could be something there I could use.